# Search client transactions data

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-permissions

I'm building an application that resembles personal financing. For that, I need to fetch information about that customer's transactions.

---

I managed to run the [GetBasicPersonalData](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/) example within the permissions service.

[Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) it says that requesting `TRANSACTION_SEARCH` will allow me to use `TransactionSearch` on behalf of the customer.

There is no such endpoint and calling the [NVP service](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/) with `METHOD=TransactionSearch` and similarly constructed `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` header doesn't do it either.

How can I use the token and token secret retrieved from the permissions service to list that customer's transactions?

---

**Update:** According to [FAQ#6 here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsFAQs/), the `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` is supposed to be used to replace the `USER`, `PWD`, and `SIGNATURE` params. When I call the nvp service that way I get:

> TIMESTAMP=2016%2d11%2d07T15%3a35%3a36Z&CORRELATIONID=f50b7296c2d28&ACK=Failure&VERSION=94%2e0&BUILD=24616352&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication%2fAuthorization%20Failed&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Comment: Holy moly! The name of the made up header varies from endpoint to endpoint. For the NVP service it is not `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION`, but `X-PP-AUTHORIZATION`. That was the final piece of the puzzle. I will write an extensive answer tomorrow. On a side note - overall, this has got to be one of the worst API experiences I've ever had. For a multi billion dollar company, this is simply embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share below useful documents for your reference:

TransactionSearch API guide [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/?mark=API%20endpoint);

TransactionSearch API reference [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/);

PayPal API Endpoint [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/endpoints/?mark=API%20endpoint)(Refere Merchant APIs);

Comment: I'm going to assume that I can call `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/TransactionSearch` with the params described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/). If that is the case, I'm not sure how this wasn't obvious to me the first time, if it is not - I don't follow. I will try that.

Comment: So I tried to call that endpoint with headers `{"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T", "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON", "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON", "X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION": "CONSTRUCTED AUTH HERE"}` and empty body or `{"STARTDATE": '2013-08-24T05:38:48Z', "METHOD": 'TransactionSearch'}` as body, in both cases I got `"Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details"`.

Comment: So my guess would be that `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/TransactionSearc‌h` is not a valid endpoint at all. And I don't see any mention in the nvp documentation of how to use token+token_secret/`X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` header either. Unless I'm missing something very obvious, the above documentation didn't help. Could you provide a simple example of a request that does that?